# How can I bind a XML web response into a dataGridView in a Windows Forms using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, forms, datagridview, datagrid

I am working in a Plugin in Windows Forms in C#. I basically send a soap request and get a response in xml. I am simply returning the response in a message box right now but I am trying to bind the response into a datagrid view. How can I do that?

This is what my SOAP req looks like the following.

```
private void getEntitySummary(long entityID)
 {
      //Create client
      myAPI.ResolvingBinding resol = new myAPI.ResolvingBinding();

      //Create parameters
      myAPI.EntityID[] entityIDArr = new myAPI.EntityID[1];
      myAPI.EntityID entityIDitem = new myAPI.EntityID();
      entityIDitem.entityID = entityID;
      entityIDArr[0] = entityIDitem;
      myAPI.DepthSpecifier depth = new myAPI.DepthSpecifier();
      myAPI.CustomInformation customInfo = new myAPI.CustomInformation();

      //Make request
      myAPI.EntitySummary[] entitySummaryRes = resol.getEntitySummaries(entityIDArr, depth, customInfo);

      //Handle response            
      foreach (myAPI.EntitySummary e in entitySummaryRes)
      {
          string firstName = e.bestName?.givenName;
          string surName = e.bestName?.surname;
          string streetName = e.bestAddress?.street1;
          string city = e.bestAddress?.city;
          string state = e.bestAddress?.state;
          string country = e.bestAddress?.country;
          string address = (streetName + " " + city + " " + state + " " + country).Trim();
          string email = e.bestEmail?.emailAddress;
          string number = e.bestNumber?.numberValue;
          MessageBox.Show(firstName + " " + surName + ", " + address +", " + number );

          // need datagridView instead of a msg box here
      }
 }
```

The code works fine and gives me response in xml format in the background. It looks something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:errdetail="http://rr.eas.ibm.com/EntityResolver/ErrorDetail" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getEntitySummariesResponse xmlns="http://services/">
            <entitySummaries xmlns="">
                <entityID>101010</entityID>
                <nameCount>3</nameCount>
                <numberCount>7</numberCount>
                <addressCount>9</addressCount>
                <emailCount>0</emailCount>
                <attributeCount>6</attributeCount>
                <accountCount>21</accountCount>
                <roleAlertCount>447</roleAlertCount>
                <relationshipCount>19</relationshipCount>
                <eventAlertCount>0</eventAlertCount>
                <bestName>
                    <identityHandle>
                        <internalID>222</internalID>
                        <externalID>333John</externalID>
                        <dataSourceCode>neutral</dataSourceCode>
                        <externalReference>333John</externalReference>
                    </identityHandle>
                    <timestamp>2016-06-28T12:24:21</timestamp>
                    <lastModifiedTimestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</lastModifiedTimestamp>
                    <nameID>444</nameID>
                    <nameTypeCode>M</nameTypeCode>
                    <givenName>John</givenName>
                    <surname>Doe</surname>
                    <culture>culture</culture>
                </bestName>
                <bestAddress>
                    <identityHandle>
                        <internalID>222</internalID>
                        <externalID>333John</externalID>
                        <dataSourceCode>neutral</dataSourceCode>
                        <externalReference>333John</externalReference>
                    </identityHandle>
                    <timestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</timestamp>
                    <lastModifiedTimestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</lastModifiedTimestamp>
                    <addressID>395116</addressID>
                    <addressTypeCode>H</addressTypeCode>
                    <street1>1111 East St</street1>
                    <city>Pikesville</city>
                    <state>AL</state>
                    <country>USA</country>
                </bestAddress>
                <bestNumber>
                    <identityHandle>
                        <internalID>222</internalID>
                        <externalID>333John</externalID>
                        <dataSourceCode>neutral</dataSourceCode>
                        <externalReference>333John</externalReference>
                    </identityHandle>
                    <timestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</timestamp>
                    <lastModifiedTimestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</lastModifiedTimestamp>
                    <numberID>6666</numberID>
                    <numberTypeID>2</numberTypeID>
                    <numberValue>123-45-6789</numberValue>
                </bestNumber>
                <bestAttribute xmlns:ns2="http://entity/results/" xsi:type="ns2:CharacteristicDetail">
                    <identityHandle>
                        <internalID>222</internalID>
                        <externalID>333John</externalID>
                        <dataSourceCode>neutral</dataSourceCode>
                        <externalReference>333John</externalReference>
                    </identityHandle>
                    <timestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</timestamp>
                    <lastModifiedTimestamp>2010-05-28T12:24:21</lastModifiedTimestamp>
                    <characteristicID>8888</characteristicID>
                    <characteristicValue>M</characteristicValue>
                    <characteristicTypeID>2</characteristicTypeID>
                </bestAttribute>
            </entitySummaries>
        </getEntitySummariesResponse>
    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

In short, I need to bind, the name, address, and number in a dataGridView.
According to the above response, it would be :

[image: datagridview]

I tried the following method but I don't understand how to get the xml response into my datagrid:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));
 ds.ReadXml(reader);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The ReadXml won't work because the number of nested levels on xml is too deep.  You end up with lots of datatables with the data fragmented with no way of putting the data back into usable format.   I will work on a solution.  Will take me a few minutes.

I parsed some of the code to get a flat result.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("entityID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("nameCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("numberCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("addressCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("emailCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("attributeCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("accountCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("roleAlertCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("relationshipCount", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("eventAlertCount", typeof(int));

            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_internalID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_externalID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_dataSourceCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_externalReference", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_lastModifiedTimestamp", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_nameID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_nameTypeCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_givenName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_surname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bestName_culture", typeof(string));


            List<XElement> entitySummaries = root.Descendants(ns + "entitySummaries").ToList();

            foreach (XElement entitySummary in entitySummaries)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                string entityID = (string)entitySummary.Element(ns + "entityID");
                int nameCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "nameCount");
                int numberCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "numberCount");
                int addressCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "addressCount");
                int emailCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "emailCount");
                int attributeCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "attributeCount");
                int accountCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "accountCount");
                int roleAlertCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "roleAlertCount");
                int relationshipCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "relationshipCount");
                int eventAlertCount = (int)entitySummary.Element(ns + "eventAlertCount");

                XElement bestName = entitySummary.Element(ns + "bestName");
                int internalID = (int)bestName.Descendants(ns + "internalID").FirstOrDefault();
                string externalID = (string)bestName.Descendants(ns + "externalID").FirstOrDefault();
                string dataSourceCode = (string)bestName.Descendants(ns + "dataSourceCode").FirstOrDefault();
                string externalReference = (string)bestName.Descendants(ns + "externalReference").FirstOrDefault();

                DateTime timestamp = (DateTime)bestName.Element(ns + "timestamp");
                DateTime lastModifiedTimestamp = (DateTime)bestName.Element(ns + "lastModifiedTimestamp");
                int nameID = (int)bestName.Element(ns + "nameID");
                string nameTypeCode = (string)bestName.Element(ns + "nameTypeCode");
                string givenName = (string)bestName.Element(ns + "givenName");
                string surname = (string)bestName.Element(ns + "surname");
                string culture = (string)bestName.Element(ns + "culture");

                 newRow.ItemArray = new object[] {
                    entityID,
                    nameCount,
                    numberCount,
                    addressCount,
                    emailCount,
                    attributeCount,
                    accountCount,
                    roleAlertCount,
                    relationshipCount,
                    eventAlertCount,

                    internalID,
                    externalID,
                    dataSourceCode,
                    externalReference,

                    timestamp,
                    lastModifiedTimestamp,
                    nameID,
                    nameTypeCode,
                    givenName,
                    surname,
                    culture
                };


            }//end foreach
            datagridview1.Datasource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might have solved the problem because it turns out my program was already serializing XML result. That is why when I displayed in a message box, it showed me just the values that I needed. I am using a Datatable and simply setting every cell value in a row:                 outputRow[0] = name;  outputRow[1] = address; outputRow[2] = number;
Always happy to listen to recommendations though :)